# Spring Boot App refuses to connect to the Kafka brokers

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

So I just recently started on using Kafka and for some odd reason, although the kafka and zookeeper servers containers are running as intended on the documentation and by using the command docker ps. I keep getting this specific error

[image]

I have been trying to solve this issue for about a week now with different configs and yet it still keeps giving me the endless loop of an error.

I followed both of these tutorials:
https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0vrqMMGQbc

docker-compose up runs perfectly fine and the broker starts but when I start the mvn spring-boot:run command that's where it fails.

I've also tried changing the address through my local machine but still nothing. Would appreciate some help

This is my docker-compose.yml

```html
version: '3.2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:19092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:19092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And this is my application.yml

```html
# Server
server:
  port: 8090

# Spring Kafka & H2
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:api;MODE=MySQL
    username: api
    password: root
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver

result:
  topic.name: result

# Keycloak
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
  realm: demo
  resource: demo-api
  enabled: false
  public-client: false
  bearer-only : true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  allow-any-hostname: true

#  credentials:
#    secret:

# Logging
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    org.hibernate: DEBUG
    org: INFO
    com.API.demo.Controllers: DEBUG
  config: src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml
  file:
    path: logs/log
```

Comment: Don't know if this is causing the problem, but in your kafka service in your compose, I'd put the environment vars in quotes. You have a lot of chars in the values that might be freaking it out.

Comment: You're using env vars from the Confluent docker image (`cp-kafka`) with a different image. Which one are you intending to use? And is your Spring code running locally on the Docker host, or also in a container?

Comment: J.Scott,  I've tried with only 3 environment variables before like the youtube example and it still has the same error sadly. Also @RobinMoffatt , I'm using the wurstmeister and I've seen some gitrepos using the same image and environment variables and they were running fine after I cloned them and yes it is running locally and its not in a container.

Answer (score 2):

The Advertised Listener is not defined correctly

Instead of

```
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:19092
```

you need

```
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:19092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
```

Also note that if you want the broker to create topics automagically you'll want to set

```
  KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
```

Comment: Still the same errors sadly, also I have a kafkaadmin configured that's why I have create_topic disabled

Comment: Did you restart the broker after making the changes? Once you've restarted it, what's the advertised.listeners show as in the broker logs? (`docker logs kafka|grep listener`)

Comment: Sorry about this stupid question but where do I find the log files for the docker? I am trying to find it in the directory but it doesnt seem to be there